# Correctly Computing Cumsum Along Third Dimension of ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, cumsum

I have a multi-dimensional array that I am performing summations along at each individual point, specifically for statistical analysis. The ndarray is 3-dimensional with shape `(1200,2600,200)`. The calculation I'm looking to execute specifically is the following:

```
cumsum = np.divide(np.cumsum(array, axis=2), np.sum(array))
```

Where array is the ndarray defined above and the axis=2 call specifically instructs np.cumsum to sum the elements cumulatively down the third dimension at point i, j.

My issue is the cumsum at point i,j which is not identical when run as shown above (incorrect result) compared to when I execute it at a specific point i, j individually (correct result). Specifically, the result is incorrect to about eight decimal places at each point in the ndarray. The data at point i,j and results follow below:

**Code that produces the correct result**:

```
cumsum = np.divide(np.cumsum(array[i,j]), np.sum(array[i,j]))
```

**Data at point i, j in the array**:

```
[2.5896627e-01 7.8833267e-02 4.6881203e-02 3.3370260e-02 2.5926309e-02
 2.1185182e-02 1.7896093e-02 1.5469486e-02 1.3617482e-02 1.2151432e-02
 1.0961573e-02 9.9725584e-03 9.1435499e-03 8.4358063e-03 7.8244330e-03
 7.2888890e-03 6.8194675e-03 6.4030001e-03 6.0309847e-03 5.6953467e-03
 5.3933552e-03 5.1191193e-03 4.8689796e-03 4.6398928e-03 4.4284821e-03
 4.2343135e-03 4.0546600e-03 3.8879570e-03 3.7322419e-03 3.5876189e-03
 3.4524139e-03 3.3257415e-03 3.2063506e-03 3.0945288e-03 2.9891655e-03
 2.8897219e-03 2.7953433e-03 2.7063680e-03 2.6220153e-03 2.5419386e-03
 2.4658246e-03 2.3931006e-03 2.3241036e-03 2.2582957e-03 2.1954644e-03
 2.1351755e-03 2.0777427e-03 2.0227525e-03 1.9700555e-03 1.9193111e-03
 1.8708067e-03 1.8242144e-03 1.7794254e-03 1.7361674e-03 1.6947000e-03
 1.6547571e-03 1.6162583e-03 1.5789805e-03 1.5431579e-03 1.5085702e-03
 1.4751572e-03 1.4428621e-03 1.4115060e-03 1.3812946e-03 1.3520514e-03
 1.3237320e-03 1.2961850e-03 1.2695953e-03 1.2438130e-03 1.2188030e-03
 1.1944349e-03 1.1708769e-03 1.1479985e-03 1.1257721e-03 1.1040850e-03
 1.0830887e-03 1.0626703e-03 1.0428075e-03 1.0234793e-03 1.0045893e-03
 9.8627270e-04 9.6843322e-04 9.5105352e-04 9.3404873e-04 9.1754185e-04
 9.0144749e-04 8.8575145e-04 8.7037822e-04 8.5544016e-04 8.4086129e-04
 8.2662981e-04 8.1267761e-04 7.9910830e-04 7.8585331e-04 7.7290280e-04
 7.6019607e-04 7.4782735e-04 7.3573570e-04 7.2391250e-04 7.1234960e-04
 7.0099317e-04 6.8992859e-04 6.7910185e-04 6.6850579e-04 6.5809203e-04
 6.4793869e-04 6.3799700e-04 6.2826090e-04 6.1868585e-04 6.0934469e-04
 6.0019240e-04 5.9122394e-04 5.8239867e-04 5.7378388e-04 5.6533841e-04
 5.5705803e-04 5.4890534e-04 5.4094271e-04 5.3313252e-04 5.2547100e-04
 5.1795418e-04 5.1054877e-04 5.0331140e-04 4.9620820e-04 4.8923609e-04
 4.8236389e-04 4.7564457e-04 4.6904699e-04 4.6256813e-04 4.5617929e-04
 4.4993000e-04 4.4379136e-04 4.3776058e-04 4.3181126e-04 4.2598948e-04
 4.2026848e-04 4.1464576e-04 4.0911944e-04 4.0366512e-04 3.9832521e-04
 3.9307532e-04 3.8791337e-04 3.8281683e-04 3.7782549e-04 3.7291663e-04
 3.6808843e-04 3.6331985e-04 3.5864810e-04 3.5405197e-04 3.4952996e-04
 3.4506238e-04 3.4068426e-04 3.3637564e-04 3.3213521e-04 3.2794452e-04
 3.2383655e-04 3.1979271e-04 3.1581166e-04 3.1189225e-04 3.0801745e-04
 3.0421774e-04 3.0047612e-04 2.9679155e-04 2.9314787e-04 2.8957392e-04
 2.8605366e-04 2.8258603e-04 2.7915623e-04 2.7579122e-04 2.7247594e-04
 2.6920953e-04 2.6597784e-04 2.6280651e-04 2.5968134e-04 2.5660152e-04
 2.5355379e-04 2.5056230e-04 2.4761367e-04 2.4470725e-04 2.4184212e-04
 2.3900617e-04 2.3622185e-04 2.3347675e-04 2.3077012e-04 2.2809043e-04
 2.2545905e-04 2.2286420e-04 2.2030527e-04 2.1777138e-04 2.1528259e-04
 2.1282790e-04 2.1040675e-04 2.0800892e-04 2.0565331e-04 2.0332953e-04
 2.0103710e-04 1.9877554e-04 1.9653517e-04 1.9433383e-04 1.9216179e-04]
```

**Performing calculation as shown above (incorrect result)**:

```
[3.61291841e-09 4.71274575e-09 5.36679989e-09 5.83235860e-09
 6.19406482e-09 6.48962573e-09 6.73929978e-09 6.95511915e-09
 7.14510096e-09 7.31462935e-09 7.46755813e-09 7.60668861e-09
 7.73425235e-09 7.85194310e-09 7.96110378e-09 8.06279310e-09
 8.15793388e-09 8.24726420e-09 8.33140401e-09 8.41086223e-09
 8.48610604e-09 8.55752447e-09 8.62545324e-09 8.69018546e-09
 8.75196893e-09 8.81104345e-09 8.86761065e-09 8.92185259e-09
 8.97392294e-09 9.02397446e-09 9.07214037e-09 9.11853881e-09
 9.16327192e-09 9.20644538e-09 9.24814803e-09 9.28846333e-09
 9.32746147e-09 9.36521882e-09 9.40179934e-09 9.43726342e-09
 9.47166523e-09 9.50505186e-09 9.53747659e-09 9.56898294e-09
 9.59961266e-09 9.62940039e-09 9.65838787e-09 9.68660796e-09
 9.71409264e-09 9.74087033e-09 9.76697034e-09 9.79242021e-09
 9.81724568e-09 9.84146720e-09 9.86511051e-09 9.88819604e-09
 9.91074511e-09 9.93277371e-09 9.95430316e-09 9.97535032e-09
 9.99593031e-09 1.00160600e-08 1.00357518e-08 1.00550226e-08
 1.00738857e-08 1.00923545e-08 1.01104369e-08 1.01281499e-08
 1.01455022e-08 1.01625064e-08 1.01791704e-08 1.01955058e-08
 1.02115214e-08 1.02272271e-08 1.02426299e-08 1.02577404e-08
 1.02725659e-08 1.02871143e-08 1.03013935e-08 1.03154081e-08
 1.03291686e-08 1.03426796e-08 1.03559481e-08 1.03689795e-08
 1.03817808e-08 1.03943574e-08 1.04067137e-08 1.04188569e-08
 1.04307922e-08 1.04425224e-08 1.04540554e-08 1.04653930e-08
 1.04765423e-08 1.04875051e-08 1.04982885e-08 1.05088942e-08
 1.05193267e-08 1.05295914e-08 1.05396909e-08 1.05496287e-08
 1.05594085e-08 1.05690345e-08 1.05785078e-08 1.05878346e-08
 1.05970166e-08 1.06060565e-08 1.06149569e-08 1.06237223e-08
 1.06323537e-08 1.06408544e-08 1.06492282e-08 1.06574767e-08
 1.06656017e-08 1.06736069e-08 1.06814939e-08 1.06892655e-08
 1.06969233e-08 1.07044711e-08 1.07119087e-08 1.07192397e-08
 1.07264659e-08 1.07335891e-08 1.07406102e-08 1.07475335e-08
 1.07543592e-08 1.07610889e-08 1.07677245e-08 1.07742677e-08
 1.07807221e-08 1.07870859e-08 1.07933635e-08 1.07995550e-08
 1.08056621e-08 1.08116867e-08 1.08176295e-08 1.08234932e-08
 1.08292788e-08 1.08349862e-08 1.08406173e-08 1.08461746e-08
 1.08516591e-08 1.08570708e-08 1.08624123e-08 1.08676836e-08
 1.08728866e-08 1.08780212e-08 1.08830900e-08 1.08880931e-08
 1.08930323e-08 1.08979092e-08 1.09027232e-08 1.09074758e-08
 1.09121689e-08 1.09168017e-08 1.09213776e-08 1.09258949e-08
 1.09303562e-08 1.09347624e-08 1.09391136e-08 1.09434115e-08
 1.09476552e-08 1.09518474e-08 1.09559881e-08 1.09600773e-08
 1.09641176e-08 1.09681082e-08 1.09720499e-08 1.09759446e-08
 1.09797922e-08 1.09835936e-08 1.09873497e-08 1.09910596e-08
 1.09947260e-08 1.09983489e-08 1.10019291e-08 1.10054668e-08
 1.10089626e-08 1.10124168e-08 1.10158309e-08 1.10192051e-08
 1.10225393e-08 1.10258354e-08 1.10290923e-08 1.10323120e-08
 1.10354943e-08 1.10386402e-08 1.10417497e-08 1.10448228e-08
 1.10478613e-08 1.10508651e-08 1.10538343e-08 1.10567697e-08
 1.10596723e-08 1.10625411e-08 1.10653771e-08 1.10681819e-08
 1.10709557e-08 1.10736975e-08 1.10764082e-08 1.10790888e-08]
```

**Performing calculation above, but at individual point (correct result)**:

```
[0.3261025  0.42537308 0.48440808 0.5264295  0.55907714 0.5857545
 0.6082901  0.62777    0.6449178  0.66021943 0.6740228  0.6865807
 0.69809467 0.7087174  0.7185703  0.72774875 0.7363362  0.7443992
 0.75199366 0.7591655  0.76595706 0.7724033  0.7785346  0.78437734
 0.7899539  0.79528594 0.8003918  0.80528766 0.8099875  0.81450516
 0.8188526  0.8230406  0.8270782  0.830975   0.8347391  0.83837795
 0.84189796 0.8453059  0.8486077  0.85180867 0.8549138  0.85792726
 0.8608539  0.86369765 0.8664623  0.869151   0.8717674  0.87431455
 0.87679535 0.87921226 0.8815681  0.8838652  0.88610595 0.8882922
 0.8904262  0.89250994 0.8945452  0.8965335  0.8984767  0.90037644
 0.902234   0.90405095 0.90582836 0.90756774 0.9092703  0.91093725
 0.91256946 0.9141682  0.91573447 0.91726923 0.9187733  0.9202477
 0.92169327 0.9231109  0.9245012  0.92586505 0.92720324 0.9285163
 0.92980516 0.93107015 0.93231213 0.93353164 0.9347293  0.93590546
 0.9370609  0.93819606 0.9393114  0.94040745 0.9414847  0.9425435
 0.9435845  0.9446078  0.9456141  0.94660366 0.9475769  0.9485342
 0.9494758  0.9504024  0.9513139  0.9522109  0.95309365 0.95396245
 0.9548176  0.95565945 0.95648813 0.95730406 0.9581075  0.9588986
 0.9596777  0.960445   0.9612008  0.9619453  0.9626787  0.9634012
 0.96411306 0.96481454 0.9655058  0.966187   0.96685827 0.96752
 0.96817225 0.9688152  0.969449   0.9700738  0.9706899  0.9712973
 0.9718963  0.9724869  0.9730694  0.97364384 0.97421044 0.9747693
 0.9753205  0.9758643  0.97640073 0.97692996 0.97745216 0.9779673
 0.97847563 0.9789772  0.9794722  0.9799607  0.98044276 0.9809186
 0.9813882  0.9818517  0.98230916 0.9827608  0.9832066  0.98364675
 0.98408127 0.98451024 0.9849338  0.98535204 0.985765   0.9861728
 0.9865755  0.9869731  0.9873659  0.9877538  0.9881369  0.98851526
 0.9888889  0.98925805 0.9896227  0.9899829  0.99033874 0.99069023
 0.99103755 0.99138063 0.99171966 0.9920545  0.99238545 0.9927125
 0.9930356  0.9933549  0.99367046 0.99398226 0.9942904  0.99459493
 0.9948959  0.99519336 0.99548733 0.99577796 0.9960652  0.99634916
 0.9966298  0.9969072  0.9971815  0.99745256 0.9977206  0.99798554
 0.9982475  0.9985064  0.9987625  0.9990156  0.99926597 0.9995134
 0.99975806 1.0000001 ]
```

Comment: Can you show the code you execute to produce the correct result?

Comment: Certainly, an edit has been made to include the code that produces the correct result!

Comment: Thanks! So the normalization is different between the two. Do you get the correct result from `cumsum = np.divide(np.cumsum(array, axis=2), np.sum(array, axis=2))` ?

Comment: Correct, it's seemingly a decimal issue, which is odd! I have avoided axis=2 on np.sum, as I was getting `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1200,2600,200) (1200,2600)`. Would I obtain the correct result with a reshape call here?

Comment: Ah, my bad sorry, I thought broadcasting would cope with that. How about: `np.divide(np.cumsum(arr, axis=2), np.sum(arr, axis=2)[:, :, np.newaxis])`

Comment: btw I don't think it's exactly a decimal issue, it just looks like that because `np.sum(array)` is fairly close to a power of 10.

Comment: I should have spotted this much earlier and saved the headache, `[:, :, np.newaxis]` does the trick. Thank you, I'll include this and credit you in the answered question

Answer (score 0):

In addition to computing the cumulative sum of each element of the ndarray along the third dimension (second axis), an addition must be made to conduct the same operation with sum.

Thanks to insight from @slothrop, the required alterations include the following:

```
np.divide(np.cumsum(arr, axis=2), np.sum(arr, axis=2)[:, :, np.newaxis])
```

Note that in order for np.sum to work correctly along the third axis and not generate a Broadcast Error from mismatching dimensions, users should include [:, :, np.newaxis] after the np.sum call.